# An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have been struggling with this error for more than 3 hours now, I am a newbie when it comes to C#.

I am trying to do a simple database connection using Entity Framework Designer.

I followed the instructions from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) to get started

Here is my code for a simple table reading:

```
using (var db = new testDBEntities()) 
    { 
        var query = from b in db.Staff
                    orderby b.StaffName
                    select b; 

        Console.WriteLine("All Staff in the database:"); 
        foreach (var item in query) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name); 
        } 
    }
```

My application fails when it gets to this line:

```
var query = from b in db.Staff
                    orderby b.StaffName
                    select b;
```

and it shows this error:

[image]

I have been googling for the past 3 hours trying to solve this, but all the provided answers do not work

Comment: can someone please provide another answer